# What to do when professor doesn't want to work with you anymore, but you want to submit past work done with him?

Tags: research-process, advisor, authorship

During the penultimate semester of my undergrad studies, I had approached a professor with a research idea, which he approved and both of us started working on it. We made substantial progress, but not enough to write a paper.

Later, I made a big mistake. I got really busy with grad school applications, job interviews and completing my graduation requirements. The later was notoriously hard because I had backlogs due to covid-related disruptions. This led to slow progress in the research arena.

The professor became really angry that I wasn't working enough with research, but I was too busy to do anything. When I communicated, he just said that I should value research more than coursework. After this, he stopped replying to my emails and told me he no longer wanted to work with me.

Once I graduated and started with grad school (in a different country), I finished the research work and wrote a paper. I want to submit this paper now. However, the professor had substantial contribution in the work so he should be an author. When I communicated with him again, he just reiterated that he didn't want to work with me.

What can be done in such a case? Would it be advisable to submit the work under my own name; or resume the project with another professor?

Edit to update: I discussed this with my current mentor (with more details) and she has said that it'd be hard to make that paper publishable in top conferences without more inputs from that professor, hence I should just put it on arxiv, drop the project and focus on future. I have adhered to that advice, put it up on arxiv and my website for record, and moved on.

Comment: You did not make a big mistake (unless there was more going on than you describe here.) Your professor was a big jerk.

Comment: @GlennWillen My mistake was starting research when I didn't have time for it. The professor is not at fault here.

Comment: You made a minor and very common mistake. I personally started and then ghosted on research projects _twice_ as an undergrad (once in junior year, once in senior year.) I did feel very bad about it at the time, but neither professor behaved like this about it. Your professor was extremely unprofessional in his handling of it. The behavioral standards for professors are (rightly) much higher than the standards for undergraduate students. (I ended up with an ADHD diagnosis a decade later.)

Comment: @GlennWillen I didn't know it was common. Well, I just hope he agrees to coauthor.

Comment: This may not be your most immediate concern, but I would like to point out that, in the interest of science, it'd be a loss if you end up giving up on the work you did and not publishing it just because of this complicated situation. At the very least you should ideally be able to post your work an a preprint, with you as the only author, and a prominent acknowledgement mentioning the professor's earlier involvement describing the situation (like an author contribution statement). I would encourage you to consider this, at least once you have an established track record with with other people.

Comment: "he just said that I should value research more than coursework."  And if the prof is paying you a stipend and the school is covering your room and board, you can take a few semester to do research.  But since you were an undergrad, I'm assuming you had to pay for each semester or there was a limited scholarship.  Expecting you to dump courses and delay graduation in favor of doing this research is BS.

Comment: I feel sorry for you. This post may not answer your question, but take it as a forewarning. If you end up publishing, you will have to pay a publication fee. Who's going to pay if you do not have a PI as last author? A pub fee can be several thousands of $. I had a similar situation with my PhD supervisor who suddenly moved to industry and didn't want to pay for my paper. Fortunately, the second last author agreed to pay on his behalf. If not, i would have lost the paper. Just keep it in mind.

Comment: @SimoneBrioschi: not all journals charge publication fees. This is domain-dependent, but in my field for instance (theoretical computer science) there are many very good "diamond open-access" journals where publishing and reading is free

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Honestly, I am sorry you got that response. You should, as a student, absolutely prioritize your requirements to graduate over research, and I believe that professor is wrong in suggesting otherwise.

Now, to the solution: You should *explicitly* ask the professor about this.
Something like:

> Dear Prof,
>
> As per our previous discussion, I have now completed and
> finished a paper with the work we started and that I finished on XXX,
> with the title XXX, please find it attached. I would like to submit
> this article for publication, and I believe you should be a coauthor
> due to the joint efforts that we did on it. I understand you are not
> interested in further collaboration, but I would like your permission
> to add you as a coauthor on this work, or if that is not your preference,
> permission to list you in the acknowledgments.
> Of course, I will handle reviews and the publication
> process in any case.
>
> Best
>
> whoisit

Ideally the Prof responds with either of those options. If the prof does not respond you are in a bit of a pickle, as you should not publish anything without an authors approval, but also not giving credit is very bad. Ultimately, if this happens, you may want to forget this project and do something else, depending on how important this is towards your PhD.

Comment: Good answer, but you give the person too much power. I suggest you reword  this sentence to be "I understand you are not interested in further collaboration, but I would like your permission to add you as a coauthor on this work, or if you are not interest, permission to list you in the acknowledgments." As worded, the former professor may hold the OP hostage.

Comment: I also disagree with your last paragraph. As long the OP makes a reasonable effort to include the former professor, that person should not get to veto or block the publicaiton.

Comment: @RichardErickson Agree with the first. My point was more on the lines "have it in writting" The second point: yeah, you are correct, but at the same time, expect possible issues in the future if the omitted professor never replies and you publish without him. Possible to do, but also giving a possibly malicious person ammunition.

Comment: That's a good point about the ammunition. In this case, it might be better for the OP to (sadly) give up on the project and focus their energy on their current projects.

Comment: Personally, I'd write it as "if I do not hear from within X I will assume you do not wish to be acknowledged for your role in this work and submit without your as co-author". The professor is an absolute douche, do not hesitate to cut him off and carry on without.

Comment: @RichardErickson I don't love this idea, but if they do agree to one or the other I suppose it's okay. I was going to say, if you're significant enough to be a coauthor, you can't just move them into the acknowledgements. All people who contributed significantly should be listed as authors on a work, and publication requires consent of all authors. Even if the authors are dicks. But if the coauthor implicitly agrees that their contribution does not clear that bar, by saying yes to being listed in the acknowledgements instead, it is fuzzily on the right side of okay.

Comment: I don't think the edit corresponds to @RichardErickson's suggestion -- "acknowledgement to submit without your name on it" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @nanoman feel free to suggest anything else

Comment: @whoisit This is a perfect way to handle this case. If the professor does not reply to this email within a reasonable timeframe, write a follow-up along these lines: "Dear Prof. X, As per my previous email, we are about to submit an article on our work XXX. Please let me known if you are interested in a co-authorship by [reasonable date]. In case we don't hear back from you by then, we will have to proceed with submitting the article as is. In this case, we will have to assume that unfortunately you are not interested in being a co-author. Thanks, Y". Do dare to be assertive.

Comment: A long time ago in a previous life, I recall in somebody's acknowledgements "No thanks can be sufficient for the inestimable contributions made by professor ..." (which has a double meaning, and friends of the author knew full well which meaning was intended! )

Comment: Unfortunately I have to disagree with everybody who assumes as implicit confirmation through a non-response is sufficient. As llama says, anybody who contributed significantly to a piece of work should be listed as an author, and publication requires the consent of all authors. Even if those authors are dicks. And consent needs to be explicitly given. It is very sad that the OP is in this situation, but sadly being a dick back at the prof is not the answer. Not responding to "If you don't respond to this by date X, I will assume you consent to this" does not equal giving consent.

Comment: @penelope yeah, I agree with you on this. Someone not replying is not agreeing to anything, which is why I worded my post as I did. I am also surprised that people suggest otherwise.

Comment: Authorship is about more than giving credit, its also about taking responsibility. An author on a paper is responsible for for the content of a paper, and you cannot guarentee the truth, ethicallness and correctness of work that you did not do. This is also why authors CAN veto the publication of work they contributed to, but no longer wish to be publised. A lot of acadmia runs on trust, and this professor has unforntunately violated the OPs trust, but it is what it is.

Comment: I am afraid, it is tricky to submit without the agreement of all co-authors especially if they explicitly refuse to give this agreement. If the prof says no, you could ask the editors of the journal how to handle this. They usually have reasonable approaches to deceased or uncontactable coauthors. Adversarial coauthors may be more difficult to handle, but they may have protocols in place for that.

Comment: @penelope So what is the practical problem with just assuming consent if no answer is given? I do not see why consent has to be explicit. You could also say that working with someone on a research project is implicit consent to publish the results.

Comment: @JFabianMeier You could _think_ that, and somebody else could _think_ differently, and that's the practical problem. If you and the person you're working with both _say_ that, and make it explicit, there is no problem. In practice, there are many other areas where assuming consent if no answer is given ranges from immoral to illegal, from intimacy, body autonomy, and general privacy. As they say, assumption is the mother of all mistakes.

Comment: @JFabianMeier In this specific case, since the OP was working with a professor who didn't exactly demonstrate a wealth of understanding in the past, attempting to publish this work without the profs consent, with or without the profs name on the paper, could in both cases result in the prof blocking the publication or even worse, to a possible retraction of the paper after publication. Neither of which will be great for the OP. Not saying it's likely, but it is possible.

Comment: @penelope and llama: I'd disagree. If professor refuses to be a coauthor or does not react, I think it's OK to publish without him as an author but with a visible acknowledgement of the professor's involvement, e.g., something like an author contribution statement. You can't list as a coauthor someone who doesn't want to, and you shouldn't publish work featuring someone's contribution without acknowledging it, but in this case I think it's fair? Especially if OP wrote the paper themselves: if someone contributed but doesn't want coauthorship, you can still acknowledge them.

Comment: In my opinion, if you collaborate with people on research and it leads to results, you have a duty to either be a co-author (meaning doing some share of the work, taking responsibility, and generally meeting the criteria for co-authorship), or, if you don't want to be involved, accept to let others do something with the research (and "just" acknowledge you if you were offered co-authorship and didn't accept). I'd say the situation is different if two authors want to move the project forward and disagree how, but this does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: @a3nm the fact that you needed to clarify that this is your opinion (that I mostly share) makes it clear that is not everyones opinion, and thus you can't just assume everyone else thinks the same and agrees.

Comment: @a3nm What I'm talking about has nothing to do with fair. In fact, the situation is most certainly not fair to the student. What I'm saying is that it isn't right to publish without all the authors' express permission, and it isn't right to remove a contributor from the author list either, and while it's horribly unfair, I also outline some of the potential consequences for the OP if they go down this route and their totally unfair prof decides to pursue it.

Answer (score 18):

Sorry your undergrad mentor was a jerk.
You're almost certainly better off not working with them anymore.

> What can be done in such a case? Would it be advisable to submit the work under my own name; or resume the project with another professor?

Talk to your current graduate advisor.
A lot of this is context dependent that cannot be captured online.
You current professor can help you see the big picture with questions such as

- Is this paper the best use of your time? You might be better off just working on your graduate project. I had a PhD committee member tell me that about papers from my PhD dissertation during my postdoc. It's not personal, it's just business.
- How good is your projects and how likely is the paper to be published? I have observed that many people do not understand what it takes to write a publishable paper until they have experience.
- What are the ethics and norms for your specific field?

Comment: If your current supervisor feels like trying to publish this paper is a good use of your time, you could cc them on the email above and they can help  arbitrate.

Comment: @Dawn is right, bringing your current supervisor into the discussion with your undergrad mentor might be a good way forward. Depending on the details of the situation it might even make sense for your current supervisor to directly write to your undergrad mentor (e.g. if they have some previous contact).

Answer (score 0):

Keep your contributions to the paper and remove any/all contributions from this professor. This might require some newly written and/or updated sections, but it is worth it. Once you have revised this paper to the point in which it reflects YOUR voice, submit it as a new solo-authored paper for publication consideration. Best wishes to you on this leg of your academic/professional journey!

Answer (score -2):

From a legal point of view, if he contributed to the work, he has intellectual property rights over it, therefore it is not possible to submit the article without his permission. Most journals will ask you to confirm that you obtained the permission from all authors.
Is it possible to edit the paper substantially, so that it's your contribution only? You did not disclose much details on the content, so it's hard to understand and give advice.
From the last part of your answer, it seems that you already tried to contact him again and he confirmed he doesn't want to collaborate with you, so if you insist it might be seen as harassment (depending on your jurisdiction).
Maybe you can ask advice to someone in his department who can mediate between you and him

Comment: I'm not a lawyer but I think "intellectual property" covers the written form of the work (here, the paper), not the idea; and the writing here was done by the student who's asking. The question is about academic ethics, not intellectual property law. (I agree with you that there would be an intellectual property aspect as well if the professor had been involved in the writing.)

Comment: I am an attorney. Intellectual property covers much more than just the writing, for example, the data provided, the figures, software etc. The OP did not disclose many details about the content of the article, so why are you claiming that the writing has been done by the student only? But even then, IP is a different concept than just the copyright of the written text. I imagine that the 4 people who downvoted my answer are not lawyers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification! I agree that copyright could extend to other things like figures, code, data, etc. I guess that from the question I suspected that the "involvement" of the professor was just discussing ideas and providing guidance, with the student afterwards writing the paper and preparing the deliverables that may be copyrightable. But I agree this is just an assumption, maybe unwarranted from what the question says.

Comment: About the downvotes, I think the reason may be that your answer gives the impression that this is a question about intellectual property. While I agree there may potentially be copyright concerns, I think the question is mostly one about professional ethics (authorship, etc.). I guess the OP is more worried about potential damage to their career because they violated academic norms, not about getting sued for copyright infringement. This is just my interpretation however!